# Отловить и вывести изменения по определенному полю

Tags: mysql, sql

Имеем такую таблицу

```
CREATE TABLE result (
  id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  branch_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  ip varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  ping int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  interface varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  mac varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  abbrev_mac varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  vender varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  ext_data int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  year year(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000',
  month int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  week int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id (id`),
  KEY `index_ip (ip)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=255028 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Я не волшебник, а только учусь, поэтому с SQL у меня туговато бывает.

```
Есть запрос
SELECT * from  ping_and_arp.result
WHERE interface != "I" and week between 1 and 15
group by ip, mac
```

При выводе встречаются записи такого вида. Сменился mac

| id | branch_id | ip | ping | interface | mac | abbrev_mac | vender | ext_data | year | month | week |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 41441 | 2 | 10.101.0.30 | 1 | D | 00:20:D2:50:92:16 | 00:20:D2 | RAD DATA COMMUNICATIONS LTD. | 1 | 2021 | 4 | 15 |
| 6244 | 2 | 10.101.0.30 | 1 | D | 00:20:D2:50:9D:D4 | 00:20:D2 | RAD DATA COMMUNICATIONS LTD. | 1 | 2021 | 4 | 14 |

Если сделать так

```
SELECT * from  ping_and_arp.result
WHERE interface != "I" and week between 1 and 15 and ip = "10.101.0.30"
order by week
```

| id | branch_id | ip | ping | interface | mac | abbrev_mac | vender | ext_data | year | month | week |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23124 | 2 | 10.101.0.30 | 1 | D | 00:20:D2:50:9D:D4 | 00:20:D2 | RAD DATA COMMUNICATIONS LTD. | 1 | 2021 | 3 | 12 |
| 49856 | 2 | 10.101.0.30 | 1 | D | 00:20:D2:50:9D:D4 | 00:20:D2 | RAD DATA COMMUNICATIONS LTD. | 1 | 2021 | 4 | 13 |
| 6244 | 2 | 10.101.0.30 | 1 | D | 00:20:D2:50:9D:D4 | 00:20:D2 | RAD DATA COMMUNICATIONS LTD. | 1 | 2021 | 4 | 14 |
| 41441 | 2 | 10.101.0.30 | 1 | D | 00:20:D2:50:92:16 | 00:20:D2 | RAD DATA COMMUNICATIONS LTD. | 1 | 2021 | 4 | 15 |

То видно, что mac на 15 неделе другой

Как вывести все записи, у которых сменился mac?
Если бы скажем еще были записи, ну до 18 недели, а смена была на 17. То мне нужны с 14, 15, 18 неделя, как раз последние где встрчается разный mac

Answer (score 1):

Ну типа так:

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT *,
                     LAG(mac) OVER (PARTITION BY ip ORDER BY week) previous_mac,
                     LEAD(mac) OVER (PARTITION BY ip ORDER BY week) next_mac
              FROM result )
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE previous_mac IS NOT NULL
  AND next_mac IS NOT NULL
  AND (    (mac != previous_mac)
        OR (mac != next_mac) )
ORDER BY ip, week
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ee438a8410d19f6fd4ee2cfa9aeb73cb

Comment: Я забыл указать версию MqSQL сервера - стоит версия 5.5.64 и пример не могу проверить.

Comment: @mafiya25 А с такой древнючей версией только что на переменных решать....